# How to format the CPP way?

Tags: c++, stream, format

I have a path constant which should be formatted:

```
using std::string;

const string PATH = "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d/value";
```

Currently I only now how to do this the C-way with `asprintf`:

```
char * path;

asprintf(&path, "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d/value", 44);

/* use path */

free(path);
```

What is the CPP (stream) way to do this (Unfortunately cannot use C++11)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a [`std::stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) is one way:

```
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

...

int val = 44;

stringstream ss;
ss << "/sys/class/gpio/gpio" << val << "/value";

string path = ss.str();
```

An alternative is [`boost::format`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/format/doc/format.html), but I'm not sufficiently familiar with that to give example code right now...

Comment: How could combine this with useful constants?

Comment: @bodokaiser: What do you mean by "useful constants"?

Comment: Using asprintf allows me to define a constant GPIO_PATH with value "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d/value" which is useful to not hardcode the path. When I now use string stream I must split up the path into several constants (e.g. GPIO_PATH_PREFIX, GPIO_PATH_POSTFIX). Do you recommend a good naming convention for this?

Comment: @bodokaiser: Ah, I see.  Well, an alternative is the [`boost::format`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) library, which would you allow to retain the "placeholders" (and thus only need one constant string).